# Elasticsearch - Physical size of a bulk request

Tags: elasticsearch

We use BULK api to index multiple docs. We try to control the batch size through various parameters indirectly. But I wanted to know if there is any clean and recommended way to get the physical size of the batch prepared before sending the BULK index request to ES.

Note:Language - C# using NEST

Answer (score 2):

TLDR

- entire bulk query should be loaded in RAM
- after certain size performance no longer improves
- it is different for different hardware -- experiment to find your size

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html

> The entire bulk request needs to be loaded into memory by the node
>   that receives our request, so the bigger the request, the less memory
>   available for other requests. There is an optimal size of bulk
>   request. Above that size, performance no longer improves and may even
>   drop off. The optimal size, however, is not a fixed number. It depends
>   entirely on your hardware, your document size and complexity, and your
>   indexing and search load.
>
> Fortunately, it is easy to find this sweet spot: Try indexing typical
>   documents in batches of increasing size. When performance starts to
>   drop off, your batch size is too big. A good place to start is with
>   batches of 1,000 to 5,000 documents or, if your documents are very
>   large, with even smaller batches.
>
> It is often useful to keep an eye on the physical size of your bulk
>   requests. One thousand 1KB documents is very different from one
>   thousand 1MB documents. A good bulk size to start playing with is
>   around 5-15MB in size.